# Is the spit test for candida legitimate?

Tags: infection, medical-myths, saliva, yeast, folk-medicine

My friend sent me a test to determine if one has too much candida. I called her gullible and she got mad and sent me several other sites which amounted to the same thing, like http://www.candidayeastinfection.com/candida-test-how-to-tell-if-you-have-candida/. Is the spit test for candida legitimate? I tried it and during the day it was negative and during the morning it was only semi-positive.

[image: spit test]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, your friend is indeed gullible.

Oropharyngeal candidiasis can be diagnosed by an experienced clinician by looking at the mouth to see characteristic plaques, or by taking swabs for microbiological culture.  Blood cultures can be taken for [systemic candidiasis](http://www.cdc.gov/fungal/diseases/candidiasis/invasive/diagnosis.html). [Antibody profiles](http://jcm.asm.org/content/46/5/1647.long) are suggested as a method to also assist in the diagnosis. The differential movement in water and sedimentation rate of saliva has no known medical use, and is promoted as a way to sell naturopathic anti-candida treatments.  Since the test will often be "positive" even in the absence of a candida infection, the promoters get to sell more product.

Comment: My wife is a naturopathic doctor and she says it's not legitimate for whatever that's worth.